# How to install Nividia graphics driver for GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-prime

When I choose to install any of the nvidia drivers on the additional drivers list (in the Software & Updates). I get a system which I can just use in line mode (no grapics at all).
I can only use:
X.Org Xserver -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-org-video-nouveau

I have downloaded Nvidia driver metapackages 390 396 410 415 418 430 
and tried several of them.
Is there something else I need to do to get rid of the default X.org -- Nouveau driver first?

Comment: Do not install the drivers with binaries from Nvidia. The version for your card is 418, *can* be newer, *can't* be older. If the driver isn't offered in Additional Drivers (S&U) then add the graphics drivers PPA first.

Answer (score 1):

Remove older Nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Add the graphics-driver PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install (and activate) the latest Nvidia graphics drivers
First check the version you want on the [graphics drivers PPA homepage](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410
```

*Or whatever version you want:*

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430
```

Comment: From that link, I see that 430 is the latest version. Does that mean I should install the latest? How do I check which version is the most ideal (stable and compatible) for me?

Comment: @5areductase Well it depend on your needs, if you wanna run only a specific application/game that need for instance drivers 390, go for it. However the safest and proper way to install it is using the last long-lived branch release, which is actually `nvidia-430 (430.40)`